# libgit2 equivalent of git log

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to do the equivalent of the following using libgit2:

```
git log -z --all --topo-order
```

I'm having trouble with 1) finding the easiest way to push all the refs into the revwalker and 2) getting the results in the same order. I keep seeing older branches come up near the top, though I've tried various combinations of topological and time sorting.

My latest attempt involved calling `git_revwalk_push_glob(walk, "refs/*")`, but not all of the branches came out. One test repo has two local branches, and one (the current one) was missing.

I'm actually doing this in objective-git, but the GTEnumerator interface is a bit limited so I'm having to extend it.

**Update:** I went ahead with manually pushing refs/heads, refs/remotes, and refs/tags (as well as all stashes because I actually want more than just the top). The ordering problem remains.

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37289674/12185226

Comment: That looks like what I'm already doing, though since it's the Go wrapper it's hard to tell.