# How to run git log commands using libgit2 in GO?

Tags: git, go, libgit2

I am interested in running git log commands from go. I see that C# version has support for this (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-log) . Does the [GO version](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) also support for similar git log commands? I did some quick searching for "query" and "filter" keywords and I did not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RevWalk](https://godoc.org/github.com/libgit2/git2go#RevWalk) is what you are looking for.

```
repo, err := git.OpenRepository("path/to/repository")
log.Println(err)

w, err := repo.Walk() // returns a RevWalk instance for this repo
log.Println(err)
```

You can configure the returned `RewWalk` instance.

```
err = w.PushHead() // instruct to start from the head commit
log.Println(err)
```

If you want to log a different branch you can use [PushRef](https://godoc.org/github.com/libgit2/git2go#RevWalk.PushRef) instead. There are other configuration options to configure the starting and ending points of the log. Check out documentation for those.

Use the [Iterate](https://godoc.org/github.com/libgit2/git2go#RevWalk.Iterate) method to go through the commit list. You need to pass it a function that will be called for each commit in the list.

```
w.Iterate(func(c *git.Commit) bool {
    fmt.Println(c.Message())
    return true  // return false when you want to stop iterating
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could at least emulate a git log by using the [`Commit.Parent` method](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/pull/29/files) which allows to access to the parent of a commit (from [`commit.go`](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/blob/8eaae73f85dd3df78df80d2dac066eb0866444ae/commit.go#L57-L65)).

Beside that, I did not see a direct call to git log.